# Does a cloud function have the same cost as a regular query from client?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a firebase realtime database with the nodes

```
myRealtimeDatabase/members
```

In members I have about 1,000 records
If I would like to filter this data say I do a cloud function that queries the node `/members` I do my filtering and then return the data I'd like.

Does firebase still considering this cost the same as if I was to query /members from a client?  Or is there a reduced cost because it was done "on the server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no discount for in-network read operations on the Firebase Realtime Database. If there was (or if that ever changes), it'd be listed explicitly on the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).